# In Excel: how to add value from a column to header column

Tags: excel

In excel how can I add a value from a column to separate headers in a column
[image]

In text:
From this:

```
Product ID   Sales Organization  Price  Wholesale Price
1            Europe              100    50
2            Asia                75     37,5
3            Asia                125    62,5
4            US                  30     65
5            US                  80     40
```

To this:

```
Product ID  Europe  Europe             Asia     Asia                US        US
            Price   Wholesale price    Price    Wholesale price     Price     Wholesale price
1           100     50
2                                      75       37,5
3                                      125      62,5
4                                                                   30        65
5                                                                   80        40
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a pivot table for that. Select your entire table, insert pivot table.
Drag Product ID into rows, Sales organization into Columns, Price and Wholesale Price into Values

Comment: Thanks do you know how to add a currency value next to the price, since it isn't a number it can't be a sum and therefore it cannot be added in values